# Dynamically querying a String is Strings.xml file

Tags: android, android-layout

Normally i am using getString(R.string.) to query strings in xml file. Is there any way to query xml file via getString(""). Because in my code i want to load the string present in resource file dynamically according to the condition. Any help would be really useful for me in learning android.

-Regards,
Ron..

Comment: not clear how you are going to put strings dynamically in strings file.

Comment: Sorry for my English. I am having set of error codes and corresponding error strings in strings.xml file. And i want to display the error strings corresponding to the error code that i get from the program. Is it possible to get the strings dynamically from the xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the id of a string resource dynamically as follows:

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("key_name", "string", getPackageName());
Log.d("MyApp", "resource id is " + resId + " and value is " + getString(resId));
```

Where key_name is the name of a string in your strings.xml.

I hope I have understood your question correctly.

Comment: Sure - it's worth noting that this is slower (according to documentation on android.com) than simply referencing R.string.key_name. If you have a limited number of items it may make more sense to hardcode them. Also, be careful to check if resId == 0 which means that the string doesn't exist.

Comment: Yeah Sure!. And just a thought to share this [link](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2009/12/dynamically-retrieving-resources-in.html) which i found by searching internet regarding the getIdentifier() limitation.